# Работа с UART на Arduino и atmega328p

Tags: arduino, avr, rs232, uart

Я написал скрипт для управления шимом на пяти выходах микроконтроллера по COM-порту: посылаешь с компьютера строку вида "1;1;1;1;1\n", где число между разделителями в пределах [0,2] пересчитывается на мк в шим от 0 до 255 соответственно. На микроконтроллере по приходу данных срабатывает прерывание, которое читает из порта до '\n' и выставляет флаг, что данные получены. По этому флагу в основном цикле программы включаются функции, которые разбирают строку на числа, пересчитывают и кладут в регистры OCRхх соответствующих таймеров.

Ниже основная часть кода:

```
#define BAUD 9600
#define FOSC 16000000
#define MYUBRR FOSC/16/BAUD -1

#define T1_PB1 1
#define T1_PB2 2
#define T0_PD1 5
#define T0_PD2 6
#define T2_PD3 3

#define num_of_leds 5

float leds[num_of_leds];
int out_p[num_of_leds] = {1, 2, 5, 6, 3};

volatile unsigned char data_in[22];
volatile unsigned char *command_in;

volatile unsigned char data_count;
volatile unsigned char ready;

void set_pwm(int i, int pwm) {
switch(i) {
  case 1:
      OCR1A = pwm;
      break;
  case 2:
      OCR1B = pwm;
      break;
  case 5:
      OCR0A = pwm;
      break;
  case 6:
      OCR0B = pwm;
      break;
  case 3:
      OCR2B = pwm;
      break;  
  default:
      break;
  }
}

void uart_init(void) {
      UBRR0H = (MYUBRR >> 8);
      UBRR0L = MYUBRR;

      UCSR0B |= (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0);
      UCSR0B |= (1 << RXCIE0);
      UCSR0C |= (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);
}

// главная функция
void process() {
      // разбивает строку на числа
      char* pch = strtok(command_in, ";");
      int i = 0;
      while (pch != NULL) {
            leds[i] = char_to_float(pch);
            pch = strtok(NULL, ";");
            i++;
      }

      // присваивает значения шима регистрам
      int pwm;
      for(int i = 0; i < num_of_leds; i++) {
      pwm = (led[i]*255)/2;
      set_pwm(out_p[i], pwm);
      }
}

int main(void) {
      pin_init();
      timer_init();
      uart_init();
      sei();

      while(1) {
            if (ready == TRUE) {
                  command();
                  ready = FALSE;
            }
    }
 }

 ISR (USART_RX_vect) {  
       data_in[data_count] = UDR0;
       if (data_in[data_count] == '\n') {
             ready = TRUE;
             data_count = 0;
       } else {
             data_count++;
       }
 }
```

В итоге работает так: я посылаю "1;1;1;1;1\n" - 5 диодов горят с 127 шим. Посылаю следом "0.5;1;1;1;1\n" - первый диод притухает до ~64, а остальные продолжают гореть, как раньше.

Я тестировал на Arduino Nano - все работает так, как описано выше. А на голой atmega328p ведет себя следующим образом: когда приходит строка, зажигается (вспыхивает на миг) только один диод (тот, чей регистр в массиве out_p с нулевым индексом). Если в этот цикл дописать вывод в ком-порт, то можно увидеть, что цикл работает только одну итерацию (i = 0), и присваивает значение шим только первому регистру.

```
for(int i = 0; i < num_of_motors; i++) {
    pwm = (leds[i]*255)/period;
    print(pwm);                       // вывод: b'127\n'
    set_pwm(out_p[i], pwm);
}
```

Я понимаю, что дело тут как-то связано с прерыванием, но не понимаю, что я должен исправить. Почему в ардуино все отрабатывает корректно, а здесь значения в регистрах сбрасываются?

И еще один вопрос: каждый раз при инициализации порта ардуино перезагружается(?) - по крайней мере кат это выглядит. Как мне сделать то же самое с голой атмегой?

UPD:  Микроконтроллер Atmega328p, тактируется от внешнего кварца на 16 МГц, фьюзы: high 0xdf, low 0xff

Comment: Может проблема с прерываниями, а может с настройками UART-a. По описанию симптомов больше всего похоже, что после первого (а может и каждого?) символа, прочитанного из UART в `data_in` читается еще и двоичный 0 (т.о., как следствие `strtok` берет только первый токен, не разбирает по `;`). Попробуйте по получению `\n` сделать копию буфера, подсчитать к-во байт в нем до 0, а также копию  `data_count` и вывести их (хоть в тот же UART).

Comment: @avp , спасибо за ответ!
Попробовал сделать, как вы сказали.
На ардуино при посылки строки "1;1;1;1;1\n" `data_count = 9`; строка при получении: `b'1;1;1;1;1'`; строка после strtok и пересчета в шим: `b'127\n127\n127\n127\n127\n'`.
На атмеге так же `data_count = 9` и в первом случае `b'1;1;1;1;1'`. Во втором случае, когда пытаюсь вывести числа после strtok, чаще всего приходит это `b'12\xb7\xe1'`, иногда это `b'127\xe1'`или это `0\n127\n'`. Первый светодиод в любом случае моргает и тухнет.

Comment: Что значит "голой"? Как она тактируется? От встроенного осциллятора?

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics мой косяк. Atmega328p, тактируется от внешнего кварца на 16 МГц, фьюзы: high 0xdf, low 0xff

Comment: По всей видимости, нужно правильно инициализировать порт на хосте. В функции process первый вызов strtok возвращает NULL. Почитайте мою статью https://sites.google.com/site/vanyambauseslinux/arduino/host-klient-arduino-na-s-linux

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics спасибо за ответ! Я проинициализировал на хосте (скрипт на питоне) все, что можно было, и теперь атмега стабильно присылает в ответ то, что ожидаешь (т.е. process() отрабатывает как надо). Однако, так происходит только если отключены светодиоды. Стоит их подключить - и снова начинается описанное выше.

Comment: Значит надо схему смотреть. Может где-то земля не подключена или подтяжку нужно поставить.